# delete multiple checked files from internal storage

Tags: java, android, file, delete-file

**TL;DR**

How to delete multiple files, file names got from `util.myPos`

---

**FULL EXPLANATION**

I can delete one file by using `deleteFile("fileName")` method

But how do I delete multiple files at once?

All the names are listed in an `ArrayList`

Java code to check/uncheck while adding file name to `ArrayList`

```
OnItemClickListener getFileEditContent = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String clickedFile = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        setMultiEdit(clickedFile);

        // change the checkbox state
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView) view);
        if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
            ((CheckedTextView)view).setChecked(true);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());

            utils.myPos.remove(stringEditData);

            count--;
            if(count <= 1){
                multiEdit.setEnabled(true);
            }

        } else{
            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
            utils.myPos.add(stringEditData);

            count++;
            if(count >= 2){
                multiEdit.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Codes to delete the file

```
void setMultiDelete() {
    multiDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (utils.myPosTitle == null || utils.myPosTitle.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(addressActivity.this, "Select address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String content = utils.myPosTitle.toString();
                String cutContent = content.substring(content.indexOf('[') + 1, content.lastIndexOf(']'));
                deleteFile(cutContent);

                Toast.makeText(addressActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showDirFile(dataDr);
                utils.myPos.clear();
                count = 0;
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addressActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                        SavedFiles);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**Note** This code only deletes one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative way, this way will delete each name from the `ArrayList` one by one

```
void getDeleteFile(){
    for (int i = 0;i < utils.myPosTitle.size();i++){
        String thisFile = utils.myPosTitle.get(i).toString();
        deleteFile(thisFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, there is no method or utility in java that can delete multiple file in the same time, the only way that I could find was deleting them one by one in a loop.
because of that some parts of your code in unclear for me (`setMultiEdit` and `utils.myPosTitle`) I can not give you a code solution that be useful. but there are many threads in stackoverflow that will be help you for modifying your code.

> Sample code

```
private void cleaner(File directory) {

            if (directory == null)
                return;
            File[] tempDirectory = directory.listFiles();
            if (tempDirectory == null)
                return;
            for (File file : tempDirectory) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    if (file.delete())
                        deleteFileCount++;
                } else { // if it's directory
                    cleaner(file);
                    if (file.listFiles() != null)
                        if (file.listFiles().length == 0) // if the directory is empty (after deleting inner files)
                            if (file.delete())
                                deleteFolderCount++;
                }
            }
}
```

this is my function that I use it for deleting all files and directories within a given directory in method parameter.

I hope it's gives you an idea to modify your code for your situation. :)

Comment: Could you post how you do it in your code?I'll try to understand it if I can. `setMultiEdit` is a button and `utils.myPosTitle` was declared in `public class Utils` to store arrays

Comment: @FayZan are you can use the solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your code is great, it should get the job done. Haven't solved my problem yet because I don't know what data type deleteFileCount is from. I'll still mark this as answer since it technically did answers my question

Comment: `deleteFileContent` and `deleteFolderCount` are simply two integer variables, and it's no matter for your work. I did want to count how many file or folder directory has been deleted. You can remove those variables